# Present perfect tense with specific time definition 'as well'

Tags: present-perfect

I have found a question like below.

> I  _________ (miss) the bus and then I  ________ (miss) the aeroplane as
>   well!

According to my view point answer is this;

> I  **missed** (miss) the bus and then I  **have missed** (miss) the aeroplane as
>   well!

I thought second clause of the sentence emphasizes first clause happened before the second. So I used Present Simple in first clause. But there is no any time definition for the second one so I prefer Present Perfect.

But given answer is;

> I  **missed** (miss) the bus and then I  **missed** (miss) the aeroplane as
>   well!

Both Present Simple. I have no idea how that happens. Then I thought "as well" define the same time for both clauses, but then again there is no specific time and it leads to Present Perfect again. Confused!

Can anybody clarify this for me? Thanks for reading.

Comment: This is just horrible.

Comment: @linguisticturn Sorry, I didn't know this is a place to discuss more advanced stuff. Thank you very much for your kind reply. I will follow your instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say "I missed the bus and **now** I have missed the plane" if you were still at the airport and were trying to explain what had happened. With 'then' in the sentence, you are describing events that are all firmly in the past, and they are all a list of items with the same status. You could go on "then I missed the rendezvous with my girlfriend and then she dumped me".